# Having trouble passing in a single input to a scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a classifier that predicts the ethnicity of a dish given a list of ingredients. This is the code I'm using to pre-process/train the dataset:

```
ingredients_cleaned = []
for s in df['ingredient_raw']:
    cleaned_string = clean_ingredients_string(s)
    ingredients_cleaned.append(cleaned_string)
df['ingredients_cleaned'] = ingredients_cleaned

df.drop(columns=['ing', 'ingredients' ], inplace=True)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['ingredients_cleaned'])

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(df['cuisine'])
df['cuisine'] = label_encoder.transform(df['cuisine']) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)

lin_clf = svm.LinearSVC(C=1)
lin_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lin_clf.predict(X_test)
```

This is the code I'm using to predict ethnicity/cuisine for a single input:

```
single_input  = "romaine lettuce black olives grape tomatoes garlic pepper purple onion seasoning garbanzo beans feta cheese crumbles"

# clean it
single_input_cleaned = clean_ingredients_string(single_input, True)

# vectorize it
vectorized_string = vectorizer.fit_transform([single_input_cleaned])

# predict
lin_clf.predict(vectorized_string)
```

And this is where I'm gettingt this error: `ValueError: X has 16 features per sample; expecting 2685`. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to solve this issue; all help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you try vectorizer.transform only instead of fit transform on your 2nd last line ?

Comment: Yes that works thank you so much! Would you mind explaining why `transform` worked vs. `fit_transform`?

Comment: I have created an answer with an explanation, if it helped you please mark it as correct. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vectorizer.transform` only instead of `fit_transform` on your 2nd last line.

You are only supposed to fit once (on the train data) and transform multiple times (on the test / validation etc).

If you run fit_transform on the test case you are creating a version which will not be consistent with the previous cases.

This is a good explanation https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/whats-the-difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models/12346#12346